# decompressing Multibit wallet private key in another wallet

Tags: private-key, multibit

I have some bitcoin amount in my Multibit wallet. unfortunately i can not figure the password I put on it for transferring coins for the life of me despite trying all possible passwords i could think of. But i do have a back up copy of my private key and if you are familiar with multibit wallet you know upon backing private key it asks you to password protect your backup and i do have that password. so how can i impart this private key in another wallet and decompress it there? is there any wallet that can do it?
I do appreciate your help and comment.

Answer (score -1):

Check out https://github.com/gurnec/btcrecover/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#btcrecover-tutorial to brute-force the password, however, you will need many CPUs. If you need help, contact me.